# Matlab: Surf 2d matrix with predefined X-Values

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, 3d

I have a matrix called 'totalAverage' with this size:

```
 size(totalAverage)

 ans =

     65   110
```

When I run `surf(totalAverage))` it shows a 3d-surf plot.

However I want X-values of surf plot be mapped with special values brought from a matrix called `time_matrix_filtered`. Currently surf plot is labeled from (1-110) according to matrix size in AXIS-X.

How can I plot the same surf but have X-Values brought from `time_matrix_filtered`? I tried something like `surf(time_matrix_filtered,totalAverage)` which works for `plot` but I don't know the right notation for this special case?

Size of time_matrix_filtered is as below:

```
size(time_matrix_filtered)

ans =

   110     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Y values too:

`surf(time_matrix_filtered, 1:65, totalAverage)`